# Input string was not in a correct format (double)

Tags: c#, double, string-parsing

I'm trying to convert a string (ex. "0.20055") to its equivalent double.

I already know that for some reason that string does not contain a valid double, but I don't understand why.

I really need to be able to convert this string to a double... Could anyone explain me why it's not a valid double? And how to fix this?

Here is some of my code:

```
double[] values_in_double = null;
string[] values_in_string = lines[j].Split(',');
for(int x=0; x < numCols; x++)
{
    double val;
    bool r = double.TryParse(values_in_string[x],out val);
    if (!r)
        return;
    values_in_double[x] = Convert.ToDouble(values_in_string[x]);

}
```

As you can see I have a `string[]` of lines, in which a line is like:

0.20055,0.37951,0.39641,2.0472,32.351,0.38825,0.24976,1.3305,1.1389,0.50494

and I split them. But then I need to convert each one to a double value.

Comment: why do you `return` if one of the values doesn't convert? why not just `continue`? `return` will exit whatever method you're in, `continue` will just skip that item and continue with the next one. At the very least, you may want to call `break`, which will break out of the `for` loop and continue with whatever code you have after it. Or check my answer for a slightly different way to do this.

Comment: I return if TryParse returns false because for this case, I have no interest if some value is not converted, I cant lose data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main changes I would make to your code are to

1. remove the `return` statement since that will exit our method prematurely
2. use a `List<double>` to store your doubles (you don't have to declare a size ahead of time, which is nice because we don't know for sure how many items in the string will successfully convert to a double)
3. to use the `val` variable when adding it to the `List`, since `double.TryParse` has assigned the value to this variable already.

I also added a check to ensure that the variable `numRows` is not larger than the string array, because that would cause an exception in our loop:

```
// Mock values read from file
var input = new StringBuilder();
input.Append("0.20055,0.37951,0.39641,2.0472,32.351,0.38825,0.24976,1.3305‌​,");
input.Append("1.1389,0.50494,0.24‌​976,0.6598,0.1666,0.‌​24976,497.42,0.73378‌​,");
input.Append("2.6349,0.24976,0.14‌​942,43.37,1.2479,0.2‌​1402,0.11998,0.47706‌​,");
input.Append("‌​0.50494,0.60411,1.4‌​582,1.7615,5.9443,0.‌​11788,593.27,0.50‌​591,");
input.Append("0.12804,0.66295,0.14942,94.14,‌​3.8772,0.56393,0.214‌​02,1.741,");
input.Append("1.5‌​225,49.394,0.1853,0.‌​11085,2.042,0.051402,0.12804,114‌​.42,");
input.Append("71.05,1.0097,348690,0.12196,0.39‌​718,0.87804,0.37854,‌​0.25792,");
input.Append("2.2437,2.248‌​,0.001924‌​,8.416,5.1372,82.658‌​,4.4158,7.4277");

string[] values_in_string = inputString.ToString().Split(',');

// Declare values_in_double as a List so we don't have to worry about sizing
List<double> values_in_double = new List<double>();

// We will get errors if numCols is larger than our string array, so to be safe,
// set a variable that is the smallest of either numCols or our string array length
var numIterations = Math.Min(numCols, values_in_string.Length);

for (int x = 0; x < numIterations; x++)
{
    double val;

    // If TryParse succeeds, 'val' will contain the double value, so add it to our List
    if (double.TryParse(values_in_string[x], NumberStyles.Any, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out val))
    {
        values_in_double.Add(val);
    }
}
```

There is also a much shorter way to write this code. The line basically says: For each item in `values_in_string`, Where `double.TryParse` returns `true`, Select `val` (the item as a value) And convert all the `val` items into a `List`:

```
string[] values_in_string = inputString.ToString().Split(',');
double val = 0;

List<double> values_in_double = values_in_string
    .Where(value => double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out val))
    .Select(v => val)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the code, what I don't understand is why the string is still being incompatible to its double... Because to all of them, the TryParse returns false, except one that it's not a double...

Comment: Then it must be your culture settings, because it works fine for me on en-us. Not all cultures use periods as the decimal marker. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark

Comment: how to I set my culture settings to en-us?

Comment: I updated the `double.TryParse` call to use `InvariantCulture`. Give that a try

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Double.TryParse(values_in_string[x], NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out val);

Answer (score 0):

change

```
double[] values_in_double = null;

    string[] values_in_string = lines[j].Split(',');
```

to

```
string[] values_in_string = lines[j].Split(',');
int arraySize = values_in_string.Length;
double[] values_in_double = new double[arraySize];
```

as you use

```
double[] values_in_double = null;
```

and value cannot be assign to null array

Comment: Done that but it still can't convert the string

Comment: what is the error saying after this code I have tried this in my machine and working well. send your code after this correction. i will help you

Comment: can you show me "values_in_string" or "lines[j]" string

Comment: The error message says that the input string is in incorrect format.

Comment: `string[] values_in_string = lines[j].Split(',');
                int arraySize = values_in_string.Length;
                double[] values_in_double = new double[arraySize];

                for (int x=0; x < numCols; x++)
                {
                    double val;
                    bool r = double.TryParse(values_in_string[x],out val);
                    if (!r)
                        return;
                    values_in_double[x] = Convert.ToDouble(values_in_string[x]);
}`

Comment: it is fine , now send me lines[j]

Comment: values_in_string[65]:["0.20055"]["0.37951"]["0.39641"]["2.0472"]["32.351"]... and so on

Comment: The first element of lines: 0.20055,0.37951,0.39641,2.0472,32.351,0.38825,0.24976,1.3305,1.1389,0.50494,0.24976,0.6598,0.1666,0.24976,497.42,0.73378,2.6349,0.24976,0.14942,43.37,1.2479,0.21402,0.11998,0.47706,0.50494,0.60411,1.4582,1.7615,5.9443,0.11788,0.14942,94.14,3.8772,0.56393,0.21402,1.741,593.27,0.50591,0.12804,0.66295,0.051402,0.12804,114.42,71.05,1.0097,1.5225,49.394,0.1853,0.11085,2.042,0.37854,0.25792,2.2437,2.248,348690,0.12196,0.39718,0.87804,0.001924,8.416,5.1372,82.658,4.4158,7.4277,0

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line :

```
double[] values_in_double = null;
```

into

```
double[] values_in_double = new double[numCols];
```

Because otherwise the code you provided wouldn't run since the array is not defined (cannot be null).

Comment: Yes, i've done that, but it still considers the string is not a valid double

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have with that is the culture definition on your PC or server, if the delimitator are ',' the sistem interpret '.' as a char.

Use like this:

```
        double vValue;
        string[] vValuesString = vLines[j].Split(',');
        double[] vValuesDouble = new double[vValuesString.Length];

        for (int x = 0; x < vValuesString.Length; x++)
            if (double.TryParse(vValuesString[x], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out vValue))
                return; 'or use' continue;'or use' vValuesDouble[x] = 0;
            else vValuesDouble[x] = vValue;
```

NOTES:

- Instance your 'double[] vValuesDouble = new double[vValuesString.Length];', you can't asing a value to a null array.
- When you use a TryParce the out var return with the result of convert string to a double, you don't need to re-convert it again.
- Never declare variable in a loop, it get declare and instace every run of loop.
- TryParce return a bool value that indicates the result of convert you don't need declare and instance a var, just use it in a if.
- Use some protocol to define your variable's name.
- Try to resume your code the most posible you can.
- I put the entire using System.Globalization, but you can declare the using on top or define your System.Globalization for your entire aplication.
- And last, sorry for my english, is not my first languaje.

Best.